# How to webstream into OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, webcam

I am trying to stream a webcam video to openCV.
The sending computer sends using

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="webcam" -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k  -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://mymachine:8888/live.sdp
```

which I can receive using

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer  -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://mymachine:8888/live.sdp?tcp
```

(I have to start the ffplay before I start ffmpeg)

In OpenCV:

```
VideoCapture capturedVideo = new VideoCapture();
boolean isOpened = capturedVideo.open("rtsp://mymachine:8888/live.sdp?tcp"); 
capturedVideo.read(cameraMat);
```

without success: isOpened returns false after a timeout.

Comment: For a simple tutorial check this site: https://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-process-live-video-stream-using-ffmpeg-and-opencv

Comment: @zindarod almos there. Only, in that article the image runs through OpenCV on the sender side, I need it on the receiver side.

Comment: I've mostly used Gstreamer to stream video with OpenCV but the few times that I used FFMPEG, I used ffmpeg+ffserver with OpenCV. https://www.alkannoide.com/2013/07/04/play-with-ffserver-a-quick-overview/